# preg_match_all пропускает значения

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, парсер

Всем привет, написал легкий парсер, который выдирает из xml файла ip adress и домен, которые взяты в теги ,

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://belgie.by/lists_access_xml-20e099e06f2671dced2efe25687f6f0461d0c0ca0');

preg_match_all("/(\-|((25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?)\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4]\d|[01]?\d\d?))(?=<\/ip>)|([a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?=<\/dns>)/", $homepage, $output_array);
 foreach ($output_array1[0] as $key => $value) {
        if (($key) % 2 == 0) {
            echo 'add address='. $value .' ';
    }
    elseif (($key + 1) % 2 == 0){

    echo 'name='. $value .'</br>';
    }
 }
```

Проблема в записи в массив, почему-то в массив попадают не все значения. Именно в 6-7 значениях наблюдается бардак... Хотя сам код в этом месте исправен
Подробнее на картинках. Первая это онлайн генератор, который с легкостью справляется и вторая - код на деле.

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Comment: Приведите кусок текста в котором есть группы 6 и 7.

Comment: http://clip2net.com/s/3nyvDP5 вот сам текст

Comment: А кроме скриншотов ничего нельзя привести? То есть Вы предлагаете для тестирования нам сперва распознать скриншот?

Comment: да невопрос! заменил линк на настоящий

Comment: этот файл - валидный XML. из него можно просто взять и достать данные. зачем его парсить регекспами?

Comment: Как говорится, на войне все способы хороши. Но объяснения этому багу нет никакого?

Comment: @Romua1d это не способ. это реально трата времени. файл разбирается встроенным средствами php для работы с xml. без аццких нечитабельных регексов

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное! Я решил проблему, благодаря Вашей критике!

Comment: @Romua1d а в чем была проблема? Как Вы ее решили?

Comment: По возможности, опубликуйте найденное решение в [ответе к вашему вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Уверен, оно в будущем поможет многим вашим коллегам.

Comment: По-моему, это проблема X<->Y или как оно там.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментариях подсказали, что XML уже и есть решение задачи. Не нужно ходить вокруг, просто берем и извлекаем из него те элементы, которые заключены в теги

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('url');
foreach ($xml->resource as $resource) {
echo "add address=" . $resource->ip . " name=" . $resource->dns . "</br>";
}
```